# SharePoint workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, workflow-manager, workflow2013

I am going to develop designer workflow 2013. After deployed it, i will take backup of site and restore to other SharePoint server on which workflow manager is not installed.

My question is that, what is the scenario after firing workflow on item creation?

Comment: You might have to publish the workflow once.

Comment: Is this a trick question? The workflow doesn't fire if there is no workflow manager.

Comment: Is there any way to use split and looping in SharePoint Workflow 2010?

Comment: I think you need to write code to do this.  SPD can not handle it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an issue if you do not have workflow manager installed on the machine where you have restored the backup.

There are basically two type of designer workflows.

1. Reusable workflows.
2. list workflows

**Sometimes list workflows will not work after restoring the database to new environment as they may be detached from the list.**

In this kind of case, Follow below mentioned steps

1. Go to list where the workflow is attached.
2. Open workflow in SharePoint designer.
3. Republish the workflow.

It will work fine..!